# Can't add migration for SQL Server database only in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Unable to connect to local SQL Server in my asp.net core application. When I try to add a new migration or update the database I get an error. This is not a problem in SQL Server (I think) because I can connect in SSMS and in a non-web application.

Connection string:

```
"Server=COMPSEMION; Initial Catalog=eBookShop; Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

SQL Server uses Windows authentication. But I am getting an error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): `Cannot open database "eBookShop" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user <username>.`
```

Also I get the following:

> Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

I can provide more information if needed and would appreciate any help. I'm really confused because my other WPF project connects to the same database without problems.

[P.S The connection string does not seem to change at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqlWG.png)

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is correct at runtime? Maybe it is not pulling the value that you think.

Comment: It looks like your connection string is mal-formed: it has two consecutive semicolons and repeats itself. Was that intentional?

Comment: The error clearly tells you that the login failed. Are you sure the web site/app pool account has permission to connect to the database? When you use SSMS you're connecting using your own account. A web application connects using the service account or (in IIS) the app pool account.

Comment: @paneerakbari, Oops, that's the print when I copied the question. Everything is fine with the line.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, that's most likely the case, thank you very much. Sorry for the rather stupid question, I'm just new to web applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was and could fix it. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos pointed me to the answer.

I went into Sql Server Configuration Manager and enabled the TCP/IP protocol

Then I changed the connection string:

```
Data Source=COMPSEMION; Initial Catalog=eBookShop; Integrated Security=True
```

And it works.